# How to export individual channels from Propellerhead Figure to DAW?

Tags: daw, ableton-live, ipad, iphone, export

I've recently begun playing with Figure again and want to import into my DAW for further refinement. Unfortunately it appears that Propellerhead have removed the ability to export only the unmuted channel!

I used to be able to get Drums, Bass, and Synth all as separate audio files by exporting 3 times, but no longer. Has this feature been removed?? Anyone know how to get each instrument as an individual channel for import into a DAW that isn't Reason (Ableton in my case)?

EDIT:  OK suddenly now it's working as expected and I don't know why.  I'll answer this myself if I figure out what's different.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain I know what the problem was now.

Figure will always export the current file, in whatever state it was last saved in.  This means if you mute 2 of the 3 tracks and export, you will not get the resulting single track you expected.  You have to mute the undesired tracks, then save, then export.

I had known this and thought I was saving, but evidently I wasn't.  Now when I'm careful to save before exporting but after muting whatever I don't want in the export, it works perfectly every time.